# last matched string is being skipped in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Team,

my last string `ml31` that is in log file is being skipped from getting evaluated and final resultant dictionary is missing its entry. any hint?

```
ml1
/core
/home

ml2
/var
/home
/lib

cpuml3
/home
/root
/raid

ml31
/home
/root
/raid
```

```
import os
homedir=os.environ.get('HOME')
print(homedir)

key_str = "ml"
val_list = []
key = ''
my_dict = {}

with open(homedir + '/backup/file2dict.result') as file2dict:
    for line in file2dict:
        words = line.split()
        for aWord in words:
            if key_str in aWord: 
                if key: 
                    my_dict[key] = val_list
                    print(my_dict)
                    val_list = []
                    key = aWord
                else: 
                    key = aWord
            else:
                val_list.append(aWord)
    print(my_dict)
```

output

```
{'ml1': ['/core', '/home'], 'ml2': ['/var', '/home', '/lib'], 'cpuml3': ['/home', '/root', '/raid']}
```

expected

```
{'ml1': ['/core', '/home'], 'ml2': ['/var', '/home', '/lib'], 'cpuml3': ['/home', '/root', '/raid'], 'ml31': ['/home', '/root', '/raid'] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the list to the key in the dict `my_dict[key] = val_list` when you reach a new key, so it doesn't come up for the last one, you need to add it at the end too

```
with open(homedir + '/backup/file2dict.result') as file2dict:
    for line in file2dict:
        words = line.split()
        for aWord in words:
            if key_str in aWord: 
                if key: 
                    my_dict[key] = val_list
                    val_list = []
                    key = aWord
                else: 
                    key = aWord
            else:
                val_list.append(aWord)
    my_dict[key] = val_list
```

---

You can improve it with `collections.defaultdict`

```
key = ''
key_str = "ml"
my_dict = defaultdict(list)

# from pathlib import Path
content = Path(homedir + '/backup/file2dict.result').read_text().splitlines()
for word in content:
    if key_str in word:
        key = word
    elif word:  # ensure not use empty lines
        my_dict[key].append(word)
```

Comment: accepting the `my_dict[key] = val_list` appreciate it. thanks a lot. I will try collections.